# Rails 4 model.where returning JSON instead of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I have a list of `contacts` in my database. I am calling them like so:

```
contacts = Contact.where(loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil)
```

`contacts[0]` returns the following:

```
=> #<Contact id: 96, client_id: 2027, branch_id: 100, phone_type: "Mobile", unit_type: "Family", phone_number: "(123)456-7890", text_message_id: nil, loaded_at: nil, created_at: "2014-03-17 22:01:53", updated_at: "2014-03-17 22:01:53", failed_at: nil>
```

I'm then trying to loop through all `contacts` in my Sidekiq worker:

```
  def perform()
    contacts = Contact.where(loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil)
    contacts.each { |contact| TextSendWorker.perform_async(contact) }
  end
```

This throws the following error:

```
 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"ContactWorker", "args"=>[], "jid"=>"3d3373e14f4bfe9ae2aa2cae", "enqueued_at"=>1395093915.4475722, "error_message"=>"undefined method `key?' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x007f40b0bd42d0>", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>1395093915.4909346, "retry_count"=>7, "retried_at"=>1395096684.1267653}
 WARN: undefined method `key?' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x007f40b0bd42d0>
```

So, it looks like my `contacts` array is actually returning an array of `JSON` objects instead of a hash. I don't think I've ever seen this, it seems that I always receive a hash when calling `Model.where()`.

What is causing this, and how can I loop through `contacts` within my worker like I need to?

## EDIT

Full class below:

```
class ContactWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    contacts = Contact.where(loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil)
    contacts.each { |contact| TextSendWorker.perform_async(contact) }
  end
end
```

Comment: What class is the `perform` method under.
And its weird that you are calling one async task from another.

Comment: Also contact is not returning json. It is sidekiq that is trying to convert your object to hash for storage so that `TextSendWorker #perform` can be called asynchronously.

Comment: @ahmed thanks for the tips, can you recommend a better alternative to calling one async task from another? Currently, a rake task spins up one worker which gets a list of contacts, and then those contacts are sent to individual jobs. I don't want my rake task to run too long. Also, I edited my post to show the class. It is in the `ContactWorker` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq serialize passed params to store they as redis, and I thing that problem of you serializer.

I recommend you follow this document 
[a Best Practices](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-jobs-input-small-and-simple)
and rewrite code:

```
class ContactWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    contacts = Contact.where(loaded_at: nil, failed_at: nil)
    contacts.each { |contact| TextSendWorker.perform_async(contact.id) }
   end
 end
```

Comment: That does it - Thanks.